# MDX Get String Format

Tags: types, scope, format, mdx, measure

I am looking for a way to detect if a measure is format_string=currency or not using Microsoft Analysis Services Multidimensional, I was only able to do a check with type:

```
WITH MEMBER TEST AS
TypeName([Measures].[Cost of Goods])
```

The above code returns:

```
double
```

The desired code is to return currency for this measure:

```
currency
```

I tried some alternatives without success:

```
WITH MEMBER TEST AS
([Measures].[Cost of Goods].Properties('FORMAT_STRING'))

WITH MEMBER TEST AS
([Measures].[Cost of Goods].Properties('DEFAULT_FORMAT_STRING'))
```

Any ideas on how can it return the format_string?